# Inject OnClick Event into running EXE

Tags: forms, delphi, exe

Is it possible with some program to to send an OnClick Event eg: MenuNewClick (File New) or others.
I have an application that has no Keyboard shortcuts.
When I use a Resource Editor I can see the Delphi Forms for each OnClick Event I need.
I would just like to be able to send these OnClick Events with Keyboard Shortcuts into the running exe.
Have used apps like Darker's Enabler, EDA Preview that allow you to modify the layout of a running exe.
Possible ?

Even this forum has options "Keyboard shortcuts
Enable keyboard shortcuts (when enabled, press ? for help)"

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If the application is indeed made with Delphi and if it uses default TMainMenu component you could modify the RCData in which the .dfm is stored (this data alows you to view the form and its properties with programs like PE Exporer and similar) in a way that you change the AutoHotkeys property of TMainMenu to maAutomatic and then change ShortCut property of each menu item to contain proper keyboard shortcut.

If you have access to Delphi I recomend you first make an example application which will have all available shourctuts implemented so you could comparison the RCData between these two applications and made necessary changes.

NOTE: What I'm suggesting will require editing the EXE resource data so make sure you are working on a copy of the exe and not on the real one so you don't break your application.

Comment: Thanks, that is helpful, here is a sample, the first is the Main and File menu, the second part is the Render Menu, say I want Atl+A for Audio and Alt+V for Video, and would I have to have the "Render Menu" open for the shortcut to work.

Comment: <code>object MainMenu: TMainMenu
    AutoHotkeys = maManual
    AutoLineReduction = maManual
    Left = 124
    Top = 257
    object FileMenuItem: TMenuItem
      Caption = '&File'
      object MenuNew: TMenuItem
        Caption = '&New'
        OnClick = MenuNewClick
      end
      object MenuNewTemplate: TMenuItem
        Caption = 'New Template...'
        OnClick = MenuNewTemplateClick
      end
      object MenuOpen: TMenuItem
        Caption = '&Open...'
        ShortCut = 114
        OnClick = MenuOpenClick
      end  
</code>

Comment: <code>object Render1: TMenuItem
      Caption = 'Render'
      OnClick = Render1Click
      object MenuRenderAudio11: TMenuItem
        Caption = 'Render to Audio'
        OnClick = RenderAudio11Click
      end
      object MenuRenderVideo1: TMenuItem
        Caption = 'Render to Video'
        OnClick = MenuRenderVideo1Click
      end <code>

Comment: I'm afraid you won't be able to use Alt+Key shourtcuts as they are not initiallysupported by TMainMenu component. The key shortucts that are available to be used are CTRL+Key, CTRL+ALT+Key, Function Keys (F-F12), CTRL+Function Keys, SHIFT+Function Keys, SHIFT+CTRL+Function Keys. So perhaps you would like to map that to Function Keys instead. If you check the .dfm that you shown you can already see that the open command has shourctut assigned and that is F3 function key.

Comment: I have made you a litle application which uses THotKey component in order to show you the numerical value for various keyboard shorctuts that you can then enter into .dfm. NOTE: It is posible that TMainMenu component does not support all shourcut combination that tTHotKey component does. How do you use it? Just ckick into shourcut edit field and then use verious ke combinations. The numerical representation of the shorctut will be shown instead of default form caption. Link to the application: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/65300398/Programiranje/ShorctuDecoder.rar

Comment: @Silver he wants accelerators rather than shortcuts

Comment: I get an error like "Could not find Ancestor for InstPopupMenu" . @David accelerators ?

Comment: @MusoBob In private Embarcadero terminology, accelerator keys are the underlined characters that can be accessed via the ALT or F10 keys. The ones that you make by putting `&` before the letter that you want underlined. Or maybe you already have those and instead want shortcuts. Perhaps I got it wrong.

Comment: @MusoBob When is that error raised? What changes have you made?

Comment: @Silver it won't run and gives an error. Ancestor for 'InstImagePopupMenu' not found. If it is too much of a problem I won't worry, don't want you to stress out.

Comment: The reason why I'm asking this is becouse I'm wondering why InstImagePopupMenu is even affected as it usually isn't directly conected with TMainMenu component. Athleast I don't know about it. Would you mind sharing which software do you use for changing the RCData resource so I can try and reproduce the problem on a test application of my own.

Comment: Also does your application perhaps use ActionManager? If it does this would change things a litle bit becouse we would have to be making changes to the actions instead.

Comment: [Link] (http://www.angusj.com/resourcehacker/) It only has Action Menu with Play, Stop . .It compiles and works ok on other changes, maybe I'm just doing something wrong. It has the some functions in right click Menu.

Comment: With what version of Delphi was the apliaction made? It is posible that Resource Hacker isn't properly recompiling the .dfm file and therefore whole resource since the Resource Hacker was made with Delphi 3 and there were some changes in the way how never versions of Delphi handle their resources.

Comment: @Silver could be, will try another, tried Resource Tuner but could not add lines, could only edit current lines.

Comment: With Resource Tuner I can change the "&Open" Shortcut to : ShortCut = 32833 (Atl+A) and the OnClick value and that works and gives me the Shortcut I need but can't find a way the insert a shortcut line between Caption & OnClick line in the other Menu.

Comment: Thanks everyone, I ended up using [Link] (http://www.autohotkey.com) as F10 opened the File Menu so I just got AHK to move across down and enter.